# How do apps recognize you after you delete them?

Tags: applications, macos

For example, there's this server based game. You delete the app, log out of gamecenter (since they claim to save your progress on the cloud) but once you redownload the app again, you return to where you left off. How is this possible?

Comment: You answered your question. They "save" your progress in the cloud - it's linked to your GameCenter account. So when you relaunch the app, it first checks with the server if there is any game saves for your gamecenter email/apple id and loads that for you. That's how its possible

Comment: But they recognize you even if you log out and log into a different Game Center account. I didn't think that would be possible.

Comment: You're saying you deleted the app, logged out of Game Center, logged into a different account with Game Center, re-downloaded the app, and your progress was still there? Did you restart your device (by holding power + home) in between deleting and re-downloading the app? Data from deleted apps is not removed until the device is restarted.

Comment: I never restarted my device because I thought deleting it and removing it from multitasking was enough. But why hard reset instead if just letting your device restart normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer access to the [UDID](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1650785/codercat) was removed in iOS 6, so they are not (no longer?) using that.

The replacement was [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor). However, once the last app by a particular vendor is removed from a device, even if an app from that vendor is re-downloaded in the future, the `identifierForVendor` will change. So that's out too.

Given that a factory reset of a device will cause the link to break (according to various reports on the internet), the best guess is that SuperCell, or whomever, is using the [advertisingIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012654-CH1-SW4). This uniquely identifies the user, regardless of app vendor, and survives deletion of apps. The only time it changes is, you guessed it, during a factory reset.